# what is the meaning of "chkAutoPick.Checked ? string.Empty : "From : " + txtDtFrom.Text" in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am new to JavaScript. Now I am checking on some old website codes. in that, I have seen the below code

```
  <%if (!chkAutoPick.Checked)
    { %>
         <label class="min-wid-label">
                <%=chkAutoPick.Checked ? string.Empty : "From : " + txtDtFrom.Text%>
         </label>
         <label class="min-wid-label">
                <%=chkAutoPick.Checked ? string.Empty : "To : " + txtDtTo.Text%>
         </label>
         <label class="min-wid-label">
                    <%=chkAutoPick.Checked?  string.Empty : "Previous Day Summary :" +chkSummary.Checked %>
         </label>
        <%} 
%>
```

I like to know what is the meaning of the below code.

```
chkAutoPick.Checked ? string.Empty : "From : " + txtDtFrom.Text
```

If I want to mark **chkSummary** as checked when **chkAutoPick** is not checked, how can I do that?

all help are appreciated.

Comment: `<% chkSummary.Checked = (!chkAutoPick.Checked) %>` something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all that is not JavaScript code it is a C# code. probably written in a webform aspx page.

it is a short cut for writing if else condition. Below is the full form

```html
<label class="min-wid-label">
  <%if (!chkAutoPick.Checked)
    { %>
         string.Empty : %>
 <% }
    else 
    { %>
        "From : " + txtDtFrom.Text
 <% } %>
 </label>
```